# Cron job doesn't work, no errors

Tags: cron, debian

**crontab**:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent https://mywebsite.com/somescript &>/dev/null
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

**syslog**:

```
Aug 26 04:36:01 web CRON[2931]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/curl --silent https://mywebsite.com/somescript &>/dev/null)
Aug 26 04:36:01 web CRON[2932]: (root) CMD (env > /tmp/env.output)
```

... both commands are schedule to run and they do seem to run but doesn't look like they're executed because I don't see any `env.output` file.

Without errors, I've no clue whats happening and how to resolve this.

Edit: There's also a newline at the end.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the `SHELL` variable points to a custom shell script which doesn't invoke the commands properly? (`SHELL=/path/to/shell-wrapper`). Also check if `PATH` is correct. Try another location like `$HOME/test.output`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Ah, that was it!  Default shell was `/bin/sh` but its actually `/bin/bash`. Changed that and it works. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default shell was `/bin/sh` when it should be `/bin/bash`. Changed that and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`printenv > /tmp/env.output`

Comment: Again `Aug 26 05:15:01 web CRON[3384]: (root) CMD (printenv > /tmp/env.output)` but no file created

Comment: Maybe a permission problem, is tmp writable for all users/groups?

Comment: `drwxrwxrwt   9 root root  4096 Aug 26 05:27 tmp` and I'm running as root

Comment: Do you have a newline at the end of your crontab file? It is required at the end.

Comment: Yes, please see my description.

Comment: Have you tried all the advice here: https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Comment: Thanks, I checked the thread and only advice that seems relevant is `Uncommon and irregular schedules` — could it be that cron doesn't understand my every min and every 2 mins commands?

Comment: Is this a system crontab or a user crontab?